# Evolution locale settings

Tags: 18.04, gnome, evolution

This morning I was proposed an update for my standard user account only. Here I have installed Evolution 3.36 which I am not using on my separate admin account.

Since performing the update along with an update of some gnome library (can't find out which one, no entries in system dpgk log for today) Evoution is all in English instead of German. The Editor Preferences contain spellcheckers for every English variant that exists but none else, e.g. German. Also, the send-receive-window does not display anymore.

How can I restore it all?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Gnome3 – sorry for not mentioning it in my question

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. Since I wanted to install Evolution only for my normal user account and not for the whole system I did it via Flatpak under the user account. `flatpak list` in the terminal window of the user account lists everything installed  that way, e.g.:

`Evolution    org.gnome.Evolution     3.36.0 (by Flathub.org)   stable user`

Next check for updates for the Evolution package by

```
flatpak update org.gnome.Evolution
```

Flatpak lists what's available, among others `org.gnome.Evolution.Locale` and `org.gnome.Platform.Locale`. This does the trick. After confirming to update Evolution is back to German. Now only that send-recv-window is still gone.